# using Rails 4 for facebook app?

Tags: php, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, x-frame-options

Ok I've been trying to research how to enable my site to work within a facebook canvas app as its just showing up as a blank. I found this website tut which seemed to shed a bit of light on why it wasnt working: [Here](https://coderwall.com/p/toddiq) and here is the [git](https://gist.github.com/shavit/5171168)

I'm not sure how to call this from my site, i've uploaded the doc to the server but how do i use it? I can only do PHP, a bit of mySQL, html and jquery etc... My knowledge doesnt span this far.

Any advice would be much appreciated heres the code that i need to function on my server:

```
class FacebookClubsController < ApplicationController
  layout "facebook_canvas"

  after_filter :allow_iframe

  def index
  end

  private

  def allow_iframe
    response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "GOFORIT"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial:
https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw

Then I put:

```
  after_filter :allow_iframe
```

In the first line of all my controllers classes

And:

```
  private
  def allow_iframe
  response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "GOFORIT"
  end
```

At the bottom.

I also added a post route to "/"

```
#config/routes.rb
  post '/', to: 'mycontroller#mymethod'
```

Source:
https://coderwall.com/p/toddiq